# Xamarin Shiny.BluetoothLE and Windows 11 PairingRequest failed

Tags: xamarin, shiny, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I develop a Xamarin UWP app to manage a bluetooth device.
For this I use the library Shiny.BluetoothLE

When i send a pairing request, windows 11 sometimes gives me the popup "add new device".
This usually causes the pairing to fail.

What can I do about this?

Just turning off the notification doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to turn off windows' own detection without affecting the pairing or connection in the application?